# Start Xorg in a k8s pod with required securityContext

Tags: kubernetes, xorg, xserver

I'm trying to run Xorg app on a k8s cluster.

If i add the following in the container part my pod description, it works fine.

```
securityContext:
            privileged: true
```

However, for security reasons i would like to remove this block, and to allow only the required capabilities.

I mount a volume to access the /dev/tty0 directory from the host and added some capabilities, but I always have the following error when Xorg starts

```
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Operation not permitted)
(EE)
```

Is there a way to start Xorg on k8s without giving all the permissions to the pod ? I tries to add the following capabilities : CAP_FOWNER, CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG but I still get the error.

Thanks !

Comment: The end result would be that the app in question is shown on a **physical screen** attached to one of your nodes. Is that really the intention?

Comment: Yep. I get the display with a vnc connection. I must use Xorg as the x server, and use x0vncserver to get the display (it's a project constraint)